# how to force input type file to accept only .html or .htm files

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, input-type-file

here i am trying to upload html/htm files on the click of a button. For that i am using 'input type=file' I have set the 'accept' attribute of it to accept only html/htm extensions like this:

```
<input type="file" name="htmla" id="htmla" accept="text/html" />
```

But it is showing different behaviour in different browsers

In firefox, it is accepting all files

In chrome, it is accepting html as well as images

In IE, the same as firefox

Is there a way to make it accept only html/htm files by any method like javascript or jquery?

**Note: I am using this control in MVC 4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in standard input control by which you can achieve it.

Yes there is an `"accept"` attribute on file input controls, where you can specify the types of files you want but this is not recognized by many browsers. So the best you can do is check the file name (extension) of file selected by user using Javascript or Jquery.

```
function ValidateFile() {
        var fileName = document.getElementById("inputFileId").value
        if (fileName == "") {
            alert("upload a valid File with .htm extension");
            return false;
        }
        else if (fileName.split(".")[1].toUpperCase() == "HTM")
            return true;
        else {
            alert("Invalid File");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

But there's nothing preventing the user from renaming an executable to `.html` for example.

Comment: wt u say is true...so i guess i have to go with this method only

Comment: Yes you can use this. It will help you alot but as I 'hv said that `it is not possible to prevent user from renaming executable to .html`. So if it is not major concern for you then you can use it.:)

Comment: I am confused as to what method i should apply.Both urs and the answer given by @Scy work fine..but which is better?

Comment: You can try any one of them. Scy did the same work using Regular expression and I did using simple string.split. So it's upto you. if you don't want more `if/else` then you can try @scy solution.

Comment: den i guess i should go with ur method..it looks simple enough and will be easy to explain to others ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is HTML5 specific attribute. Not all browsers support it yet. For those that doesn't you will have to perform the check on the server. Another possibility is to check the extension of the file that was selected using javascript. Basically you could get the selected filename like this: `$('#htmla').val()`. And then regex for the extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  function test(obj,filter){

    var file = obj.value.match(/[^\/\\]+$/gi)[0];
    var rx = new RegExp('\\.(' + (filter?filter:'') + ')$','gi');
    if(filter&&file&&!file.match(rx)){
      alert("check the file type, only html is accepted");
      //input file
      //it's totally a bad idea...
      //document.body.innerHTML = "<input type='file' onchange=\"test(this,'html');\" >";

    }
  }
</script>
<body>
    <input id="inputFile" type="file" onchange="test(this,'html');">
</body>
```

maybe this should be for you [swfupload](https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/)

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML =` is a bad idea if there are more elements on the page then just the input element. either just replace only the input element or change its value.

Comment: your method works fine...but i am confused as to which method should i go for..yours or @Sachin's..which is better?

Comment: either way, it's not important. you must verify file type at background.